# Custom Control with inner html C#

Tags: .net, custom-controls

I would like to create a custom control in which i should be able to have some child controls like in asp panel.

```
<custom:panel runat="server" id="CustomPanel">
   <asp:TextBox id="textbox1" runat="server" />
   <span>Test</span>
</custom:panel>
```

My objective is to create a custom container and have the innerhtml same as above. I should be able to access the server side control like below in the code behind of page.

```
textbox1.Text="something";
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please find the solution below. We can use it for creating controls like rounded corner container etc.

```
[ParseChildren(true, "Items")]
[PersistChildren(true)]
public class CustomContainer : Control
{
    private List<Control> m_items = new List<Control>();


    [Browsable(false)]
    public List<Control> Items
    {
        get { return m_items; }
    }


    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        //create a custom container of our choice for your child controls
        HtmlGenericControl div = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
        foreach (Control ctrl in Items)
        {
            div.Controls.Add(ctrl);
        }
        this.Controls.Add(div);
    }        
}
```